# Div Display Issue

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that under my field that displays an *error* if there is one in a `form`.

The problem is if I use `inline-block`, what ever I do in the `div` area will be shown in the *error color*

I only want `background: red;` when the field is no longer empty.

```css
div#alert-block {
    height:15px; 
    clear:both;
}

.alert-error {    
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    height:20px;
    width: 100%;
    clear:both; 

}
```

```html
<div id="alert-block">
    <span class="alert-error">{email_error}</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you the full code for people to see clearly what you are trying to do and also improve your code

Comment: It is already display in red color. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :empty after your code.

```
.alert-error:empty {   
  background-color: green;
}
```

for more info and browser compatibility check:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/

or to further improve (not sure about browser compatibility though)

```
.alert-error:not(:empty) {    
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    height:20px;
    width: 100%;
    clear:both; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed  `width: auto` in the `class` *"alert-error"*. Try it. If there is no *error* message, then you will not get `background: red;` now. Hope, this is your requirement!

```css
div#alert-block {
    height:15px; 
    clear:both;
}

.alert-error {    
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    height:20px;
    width: auto;
    clear:both; 

}
```

```html
<div id="alert-block">
    <span class="alert-error">{email_error}</span> 
</div>
```